# Habilitar Teclado

Tags: c#

les comparto mi duda,tengo un numericUpDown y quiero qué al escribir un numero, si este es mayor a 10 dígitos bloque o inhabilite la escritura.
Debajo dejo un ejemplo de lo que llevo hasta ahora, pero ahi es donde me "atore".

De ante mano muchas gracias por sus opiniones.

```
private void nudNumSeguro_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(this.Text.Length == 10)
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes comprobarlo en el evento `KeyPress`: si la longitud es mayor o igual a 10 y no es un carácter de control (para permitir borrar) se anula la pulsación:

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = ((NumericUpDown) sender).Text.Length >= 10
                && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es lo que necesitaba :D